# Entity class from the database table

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to create an entity class from the database table.

However, when I click 'Next' it goes to the screen where
I suppose to select a schema, but selection combo-box is dimmed, so
selection is unavailable.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you haven't told NetBeans which database to connect to yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly with a database connection. In the first combobox you can create a connection and see the tables directly.

The other way is to define a database schema at first. Then you can see that in the secon combobox (New File --> Other --> Persistence --> Database Schema)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I select jdbc/sample but  i can not see tables and i can not chosse the sechema

Comment: thanks Kayser but how can i creat new schema when i add DB name it cant creat becase it did not found it

Comment: thanks but it give the following error:                                   unable to add connection cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/client using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver(Access denied for user "@'localhost' to database 'client')

Comment: @aishah-sehaim You don't have the permssion to acces the database.

Comment: how can i change the access i did not have database i would like to build it

Comment: First you should install one.